# How to make notifications come even when the app is in the background?

Tags: java, android

How to make notifications come even when the app is in the background or disabled without firebase. I use SocketIO and code with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a background service to listen for any message or events from SocketIO and build a notification after receiving any events.

Refer the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service) for making a service

Comment: Thank you! do you have any examples of implementation?

Comment: unfortunately, not at the moment, I don't have the code, but I have done a sort of similar implementation. So it should work.